# In Unity when i try to build apk i have got this error. How can i solve this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, nextpeer

Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
F:\Software\SDK\ALL - SDK\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "F:/Software/SDK/ALL - SDK/platforms/android-21\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.google.android.gms:com.nextpeer.android -S "F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\google-play-services_lib\res" -S "F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res"

stderr[
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-ldpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-mdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-hdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-xhdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-mdpi\np__ic_current_matches_on_going_time_left.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-hdpi\np__ic_current_matches_on_going_time_left.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-xhdpi\np__ic_current_matches_on_going_time_left.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StaginF:\gXSAqrea\uaanrder0o4i-d-0l6i-b1r5\aTreimeps\SNtaegxtipneegrA\rreesa\daranwdarbloe-ihd-dlpii\nbpr__airci_esc\urNreenxtptee_mrat\chreess_r\darnakw_arbiblboe-mn_dflpai\gnp___bilcu_e.curpnrge:n tl_imbpantg cwahersn_irnagn:k *riibCbConP*:f laNgo_tb lruee.cponggn:i zliinbgp kngn owwn saRrGBn ipnrgo:f ilei CthCaPt: h asN obte erne ceodgintiezdi
ng known sRGB profile that has been edited

stderr[
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-ldpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-mdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-hdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-xhdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

stderr[
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-ldpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-mdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-hdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
F:\XSquare04-06-15\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\Nextpeer\res\drawable-xhdpi\np__facebook_close.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Comment: Please try to improve your question by providing more helpful information than just a screen full of error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common Unity issue/bug at the "import custom package" function.
Just clean your plugin folder and then import the plugins again. Some times the import custom package function adds the file and not overwrite it. Causing a duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

are there multiple menifest files in your project? if so then asking same permission in many manifest files causes problem. And if you have multiple android-support files then remove duplicate ones except only -v4. hope this will resolve the issue.